# Create a list of dictionaries from a global variable using map or comprehension list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension, map-function

I have a dictionary as a global variable and a list of string:

```
GLOBAL = {"first": "Won't change", "second": ""}
words = ["a", "test"]
```

My goal is to create the following list:

```
[{"first": "Won't change", "second": "a"}, {"first": "Won't change", "second": "test"}]
```

I can do it with the following code:

```
result_list = []
for word in words:
    dictionary_to_add = GLOBAL.copy()
    dictionary_to_add["second"] = word
    result_list.append(dictionary_to_add)
```

My question is how can I do it using a comprehension list or using the map() function

Comment: Your code won't give you the result you want anyway.

Comment: @DanielRoseman fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you can do this in one ugly line. Assuming you use immutables as values, otherwise you'd have to do a deep copy which is also possible:

```
[GLOBAL.copy().update(second=w) for w in word]
```

Or even better (Python 3 only)

```
[{**GLOBAL, "second": w} for w in word]
```

Comment: how come the python3 solution?

Comment: @obgnaw what do you mean by "how come"

Comment: How you get the solution?never seen`{**GLOBAL, "second": w}`before.

Comment: Oh! So, it's kind of like the reverse of def f(**kwargs) if you have seen that. It essentially applies the dictionary as keyword arguments. So f(**{"a": 1, "b:2}) is the same as f(a=1, b=2). You can also do this in dictionaries! I'm not sure what the name of this is, but it is likely in the "keyword arguments" section of the docs

Answer (score 1):

```
GLOBAL = {"first": "Won't change", "second": ""}
words = ["a", "test"]
result_list = []
for word in words:
    dictionary_to_add = GLOBAL.copy()
    dictionary_to_add["second"] = word
    result_list.append(dictionary_to_add)
print result_list
def hello(word):
    dictionary_to_add = GLOBAL.copy()
    dictionary_to_add["second"] = word
    return dictionary_to_add
print [hello(word) for word in words]
print map(hello,words)
```

test it,and try more.

Comment: Why would you call this function "hello"?

Comment: e,just a  lambda,and i don't want repeat myself,so i give it a simple name.@EnricoBorba

Answer (score 1):

```html
In [106]: def up(x):
     ...:     d = copy.deepcopy(GLOBAL)
     ...:     d.update(second=x)
     ...:     return d
     ...: 

In [107]: GLOBAL
Out[107]: {'first': "Won't change", 'second': ''}

In [108]: map(up, words)
Out[108]: 
[{'first': "Won't change", 'second': 'a'},
 {'first': "Won't change", 'second': 'test'}]
```